# How to get a normal application menu in the top- or titlebar in Gnome

Tags: gnome

I am very sorry to see Unity disappear - for me it is the best Linux desktop interface.

I am now trying if Gnome is workable for me. One thing I hate about gnome is that it does not show the application menu in either the top- or the title bar.

Please note that I am talking about the dropdown menu applications have in their window, not a menu to pick applications from.

Gnome shows just a single drop down, adding an extra level to the menu structure and ruining the overview. For applications Like the Gimp or Blender, this is killing.

So how do I get that menu back in my top bar?

Comment: I know that place, but I can' t find the extension I need. Somehow there are plenty menu' s that show applications, but no extension that will show the menu of the application (note the difference) in a normal way - like in Unity, Windows or MacOS

Comment: Run the tweak tool and go to the Window configuration.   You can turn on the Minimize, Maximize, etc.  You can set the mouse clicks as well.  As far as I know, the menus are kind of set per application as well.

Comment: The tweaktool has no per application option. The applications themselves too do not have a way to set this option.

Comment: I just did a clean install of Ubuntu GNOME and some applications had the menu and some did not.  Some I was able to bring up by pressing the Alt Key others was right clicking.  Usually if I could get the menu up, I could go to View -> Show Menu Bar and that would turn it on permanently.

Answer (score 4):

I guess [Gnome Global Menu Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1250/gnome-global-application-menu/) is what you're looking for.

It was a work in progress back in April (see [OMG Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/04/global-menu-for-gnome-extension-development)), some applications would work, but there were problems with others (like Blender).  Don't know what's the current state, but if you feel like giving it a try, detailed install instructions are to be find in [GitHub](https://github.com/lestcape/Gnome-Global-AppMenu).